# Validating dynamically created content with jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, forms

I know that several people have probably asked this same question, but I am having a hard time finding a solution that will work with what I have. I have form that people can add as many lines (that have 4 input boxes per line) as necessary then delete them if they are not used. I am using the .append() jquery function to add the lines and have it working.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to validate the new input boxes. Does any one have a good solution for what I am trying to do? Here is a link to my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var count = 1;
$('p#add_field').click(function () {

    count += 1;

    $('table#entries').append(
        '<tr>' +
        '<td><input id="cl_' + count + '" name="cl[]' + '" type="text" /></td>' +
        '<td><input id="num_' + count + '" name="num[]' + '" type="text" size="5"/></td>' +
        '<td><input id="description_' + count + '" name="description[]' + '" type="text" size="86"/></td>' +
        '<td><span class="delete">Remove</span></td></tr>');

    $(".delete").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });

});





    // 1. prepare the validation rules and messages.
    var rules = {

        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        lname: "required",
        fname: "required",
        city: "required",
        address: "required",
        'cl[]': "required",
        'num[]': "required",
        'description[]': "required",
        age: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            maxlength: 3
        },
        phone: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true
        }



    }; // end var rules


    // 2. Initiate the validator
    var validator
        = new jQueryValidatorWrapper("FormToValidate",
            rules);

    // 3. Set the click event to do the validation
    $("#btnValidate").click(function () {
        if (!validator.validate())
            return;

        alert("Validation Success!");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9k7ph/4/

Answer (score 3):

1)  You are calling `.validate()` inside your `click` handler so it's not properly initialized on your form.  You would only call it *once* on DOM ready to initialize the plugin on your form.

2)  You do not need to put the submit button inside a click handler either.  The jQuery Validate plugin already properly captures the `click` event.

3)  Your dynamically created fields MUST have unique `name` attributes or the plugin will fail.

4)  You must dynamically add the rules to the newly created fields as you create them.  Calling `.validate()` is not the way to do this... new rules/options are ignored after initialization.  You can use a built-in method like `rules('add')`, or even easier, add `class="required"` to the new input fields and this rule will be picked up automatically.

I scrapped your fiddle and started from scratch... basic validation is working, now you can layer your other plugins back into it.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/X5EvD/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#FormToValidate").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            lname: "required",
            fname: "required",
            city: "required",
            address: "required",
                'cl[]': "required",
                'num[]': "required",
                'description[]': "required",
            age: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                maxlength: 3
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                phoneUS: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert("Validation Success!");
            return false; // if you need to block normal submit because you used ajax
        }
    });

    var count = 1;
    $('p#add_field').click(function () {

        count += 1;

        $('table#entries').append(
            '<tr>' +
            '<td><input id="cl_' + count + '" name="cl[' + count + ']' + '" type="text" class="required"/></td>' +
            '<td><input id="num_' + count + '" name="num[' + count + ']' + '" type="text" size="5" class="required"/></td>' +
            '<td><input id="description_' + count + '" name="description[' + count + ']' + '" type="text" size="86" class="required"/></td>' +
            '<td><span class="delete">Remove</span></td></tr>');


        $(".delete").click(function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thank you for your help and time! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Sparky what if button type is not submit. Let us suppose the button type is "button" and I want to validate on its click.

Comment: @KiranShahi - then it’s not captured automatically.  You would need to write an event handler to capture the click.